# How to set a default page in a static_dir in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

In my `app.yaml` file I have:

```
handlers:
- url: /resume
  static_dir: resume
```

Inside my `/resume` folder I have an `index.htm` file. I want this file to show when I navigate to `http://myapp/resume` -- how do I tell GAE that `index.htm` should be the default page in this directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your `app.yaml` after your /resume `static_dir` declaration:

```
- url: /resume
  static_files: resume/index.htm
  upload: resume/index.htm
```

Comment: Hmm. It _almost_ works. If I put that block before my `static_dir` block then I get a `500 Server Error` when I go to `http://myapp/resume`. If I put that block _after_ the `static_dir` block then it shows the `index.htm` page like I want except any `<img src="picture.jpg" />` images in the page don't show. The images _do_ show if I go to the image URL directly in the browser however. It's like the two handlers are conflicting.

Comment: @Joshua yes, you need to put it after the static_dir. Can't you just rename the images path in <img src="/resume/picture.jpg" /> for example?

Comment: @Joshua or, you can move them in a different directory (images) and serve them through a more specific /images path.

Comment: Yea, that works. I didn't do it initially because I needed my html page to still display right if I just opened it from my file system (rather than using the GAE dev server), but I just changed it to use `../resume/picture.jpg` and now it works both ways. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any way to leave the `<img src="picture.jpg">` in index.html so that index.html doesn't need to know it is in the resume directory?